# rails 3 rendering error div_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working a on rails 3 project and am trying to render a partial on the user profile page. Rendering works fine for everything except photo. When I try to access a user profile page I get the following error

> `undefined method`model_name' for NilClass:Class`

user show.html.erb

```
def show
  @user= User.find(params[:id])
  @photo = Photo.find_by_id(params[:id])
end
```

In the profile show.html.erb

```
<%= content_tag :h2, "My photos" %>
<% photo = @user.photos %>
<% if photo.blank? %>
  <%= link_to 'Create photo', new_photo_path %>
<% else %>
  <%= render :partial => 'photos/photo', :locals => {:photo => @photo} %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the partial that it is rendering

```
<%= div_for photo do %>
 <table>
   <tr>
     <th>Title</th>
     <th>Date</th>
     <th>Extra</th>
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <td><%= photo.title %></td>
     <td><%= photo.date %></td>
     <td><%= photo.extra %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'View photos', photo %></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas or suggestions on how I can get rid of this error? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think there is a little mess singular and plural form of  `photo` variables, and instance and local types of them. Hard to understand, what do you really want to do. But I can say that most likely the reason of error is nil photo variable inside `<%= div_for photo do %>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the div_for note is nil so I would try accessing it by iterating through the code Like I've done below. Then photos should be accessible now.

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
  <%= div_for photo do %>
    Code here
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown because in `:locals => {:photo => @photo}`, `@photo` is null

Note that you are sending the list `@user.photos`, not a single image.

Here `@photo = Photo.find_by_id(params[:id])` you are getting the photo by id, photo_id.  I believe you want to find the user's photo

```
@photos = @user.photos 

#for only one photo, also you need to make sure its not null
@photo = @user.photos.first
```

Comment: Thank you and for some reason when checking in the rails console a photo was nil but after adding @user.photos to my collection partial things started to work

Answer (score 1):

There isn't photo with this id in database `@photo = Photo.find_by_id(params[:id])`

And, therefore, you sending `nil` object to partial. If you want to show all user photos, try this.

```
<%= content_tag :h2, "My photos" %>
<% photos = @user.photos %>
  <% if photos.empty? %>
    <%= link_to 'Create photo', new_photo_path %>
  <% else %>
    <% photos.each do |photo| %>
      <%= render :partial => 'photos/photo', :locals => {:photo => photo} %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```